# intergrating qt4 ,vtk and visual studio2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, vtk

I have an integrated visual studio (2010) and Qt(4 visual studio addin) combination and just recently decided to add VTK5.I have managed to compile VTK as per the numerous instructions  everywhere .However i tried to build a simple example from the VTK website but i get the  Dll errors below.I have added include paths in visual studio but just can't compile .please direct me on what i should do next .

GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_QVTKWidget.cpp(73): warning C4273: 'staticMetaObjectExtraData' : inconsistent dll linkage
 E:/libs/vtk/vtk-5.10.1/VTK5.10.1/GUISupport/Qt/QVTKWidget.h(76) : see previous definition of 'private: static QMetaObjectExtraData const QVTKWidget::staticMetaObjectExtraData'
GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_QVTKWidget.cpp(77): error C2491: 'QVTKWidget::staticMetaObject' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Comment: My advice (as a person who uses VS2010 + vtk + qt4 every day for years on multiple windows machines) I would build vtk statically. Use CMake to generate your VS project files. And never ever use the INSTALL targets for VTK. Instead point VTK_DIR to the vtk build folder.

Comment: thanks for your reply but do you mind showing me how you do it

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to build a working environment following this guide, it is really helpful and well explained (and, as the more important thing, it uses VS2010, QT 4 and VTK 5): http://guitarcplusplus.blogspot.it/2013/02/itk-vtk-qt-on-window-7-64bit-and-visual.html.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the link, I'll definitely go through it when time allows as I had already given up :)