# How to have ITK and VTK libraries with QT creator

Tags: qt, vtk, itk

I'm new on QT Creator and I'm have to use ITK and VTK with QT. I installed ITK and VTK using CMake an visual studio 2013 Committee and now I have to use ITK and VTK with QT Creator. How can I use or include ITK or VTK functions on QT? Any kind of help would be perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884532/intergrating-qt4-vtk-and-visual-studio2010/17919625#17919625). It contains a link to a great guide, that I used when I had to configure my project. Unfortunately, it was referred to the old version of those tools (VS was at the 2010 version), so I hope it works for you as well.